# java mail in jsp servlet getting authentication failure exception

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail

i am developing one app in jsp servlet. in that using javamail i'm sending email to user. i tried a lot but i'm getting an exception authentication failure. please help me.thank you in advance code is below-

```
   package WhackAMole;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Properties;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;

public class MailServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String from;
private String to;
private String subject;
private String mess;
private String message;
private String password;

public MailServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

     from = request.getParameter("from");
     to = request.getParameter("to");

     subject = "Whack_A_Mole game score";
     mess = request.getParameter("sc");
     message="Your Score is"+mess;
     password =request.getParameter("pass");
    System.out.println("in mail servlet");

    try {

        /* Setting Properties for STMP host */
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(from, password);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessage.setText(message);
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", "Authentication failed");


    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", "Wrong email address");

        /*RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(err);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);*/

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ex.getMessage());

        /*RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(err);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);*/
    }
    /*RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(succ);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);*/

}

private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public SMTPAuthenticator(String login, String password) {
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(login, password);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    System.out.println("in servlet...........");
}

   }
```

error-

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two jars into the WEB-INF/lib directory :

1. [mail.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar) - contains the actual smtp implmentation
2. [activation.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar) - needed by mail.jar

Comment: getting exception-  java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:609)
 javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:569)
 javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:105)
 WhackAMole.MailServlet.processRequest(MailServlet.java:71)
 WhackAMole.MailServlet.doPost(MailServlet.java:127)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: Make sure you parameter is not null.

Comment: YEAH.PARAMETERS ARE NOT NULL

Comment: when we add jar files in project it doesn't get stored in lib of web inf.have to put it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems missing class, add [Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) jar in server lib folder.